# Plotting Unsorted Dataframes with Plotly Scatter Plots

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

Whenever I try to plot data using the plotly python library (in this case from `Modeanalytics dataframe`), it ends up connecting out-of-order data points together and causing a mess as follows:

[image: messy plot]

If I sort my data with the SQL query that genrates the dataframe, then the plot looks great!

[image: clean plot]

However, I want to actually sort the data in python and not in SQL.

I attempted to take the out-of-order dataframe and do this:

```
df.sort_values(by=['time'])
```

but it still resulted in the messy plot.

How can I sort my data frame in python such that it is plotted correctly?

Comment: Please remove the `r` tag.

Comment: @pault removed, and thank you so much for your help, that solved my problem! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default [`sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) returns a new dataframe without modifying the original.

You can either set the flag to `True` or assign the output back to the original dataframe.

Try:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['time'])
```

Or

```
df.sort_values(by=['time'], inplace=True)
```